# Passing multiple selected values from dropdown in html

Tags: javascript, html

I am using this below code to send parameters to a php page.

```
var client=document.getElementById("client").value;
var received=document.getElementById("received").value;   
 window.open('ajax_report.php?client='+client+'&received='+received,'_blank', 'scrollbars=yes,menubar=no,height=600,width=800,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,fullscreen=yes,status=no');
```

Now the problem is that client is a select drop down in html which takes multiple values. If multiple values are selected,on sending parameters, only first of selected values is being sent. How to send all the selected values in multiple select dropdown

Comment: How about cookie storing values and retrieve at ajax_report.php?

Comment: Loop thru selected values and combine them into comma-separated string.